# Find max of count on group by

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate, aggregation

I am having some trouble answering the following question.

For each age value that appears in the Student table, find the level value that
appears most often. For example, if there are more FR level students aged 18 than SR,
JR, or SO students aged 18, you should print the pair (18, FR).

from this data set.

```
create database university;
use university;

create table student(
    snum decimal(9) primary key,
    sname varchar(30),
    major varchar(25),
    level varchar(2),
    age int
    );
create table faculty(
    fid decimal(9) primary key,
    fname varchar(30),
    deptid decimal(2)
    );
create table class(
    cname varchar(40) primary key,
    meets_at varchar(20),
    room varchar(10),
    fid decimal(9),
    foreign key(fid) references faculty(fid)
    );
create table enrolled(
    snum decimal(9),
    cname varchar(40),
    primary key(snum,cname),
    foreign key(snum) references student(snum),
    foreign key(cname) references class(cname)
    );

insert into student values(051135593,'Maria White','English','SR',21);
insert into student values(060839453,'Charles Harris','Architecture','SR',22);
insert into student values(099354543,'Susan Martin','Law','JR',20);
insert into student values(112348546,'Joseph Thompson','Computer Science','SO',19);
insert into student values(115987938,'Christopher Garcia','Computer Science','JR',20);
insert into student values(132977562,'Angela Martinez','History','SR',20);
insert into student values(269734834,'Thomas Robinson','Psychology','SO',18);
insert into student values(280158572,'Margaret Clark','Animal Science','FR',18);
insert into student values(301221823,'Juan Rodriguez','Psychology','JR',20);
insert into student values(318548912,'Dorthy Lewis','Finance','FR',18);
insert into student values(320874981,'Daniel Lee','Electrical Engineering','FR',17);
insert into student values(322654189,'Lisa Walker','Computer Science','SO',17);
insert into student values(348121549,'Paul Hall','Computer Science','JR',18);
insert into student values(351565322,'Nancy Allen','Accounting','JR',19);
insert into student values(451519864,'Mark Young','Finance','FR',18);
insert into student values(455798411,'Luis Hernandez','Electrical Engineering','FR',17);
insert into student values(462156489,'Donald King','Mechanical Engineering','SO',19);
insert into student values(550156548,'George Wright','Education','SR',21);
insert into student values(552455318,'Ana Lopez','Computer Engineering','SR',19);
insert into student values(556784565,'Kenneth Hill','Civil Engineering','SR',21);
insert into student values(567354612,'Karen Scott','Computer Engineering','FR',18);
insert into student values(573284895,'Steven Green','Kinesiology','SO',19);
insert into student values(574489456,'Betty Adams','Economics','JR',20);
insert into student values(578875478,'Edward Baker','Veterinary Medicine','SR',21);
insert into faculty values(142519864,'Ivana Teach',20);
insert into faculty values(242518965,'James Smith',68);
insert into faculty values(141582651,'Mary Johnson',20);
insert into faculty values(011564812,'John Williams',68);
insert into faculty values(254099823,'Patricia Jones',68);
insert into faculty values(356187925,'Robert Brown',12);
insert into faculty values(489456522,'Linda Davis',20);
insert into faculty values(287321212,'Michael Miller',12);
insert into faculty values(248965255,'Barbara Wilson',12);
insert into faculty values(159542516,'William Moore',33);
insert into faculty values(090873519,'Elizabeth Taylor',11);
insert into faculty values(486512566,'David Anderson',20);
insert into faculty values(619023588,'Jennifer Thomas',11);
insert into faculty values(489221823,'Richard Jackson',33);
insert into faculty values(548977562,'Ulysses Teach',20);
insert into class values('Data Structures','MWF 10','R128',489456522);
insert into class values('Database Systems','MWF 12:30-1:45','1320 DCL',142519864);
insert into class values('Operating System Design','TuTh 12-1:20','20 AVW',489456522);
insert into class values('Archaeology of the Incas','MWF 3-4:15','R128',248965255);
insert into class values('Aviation Accident Investigation','TuTh 1-2:50','Q3',011564812);
insert into class values('Air Quality Engineering','TuTh 10:30-11:45','R15',011564812);
insert into class values('Introductory Latin','MWF 3-4:15','R12',248965255);
insert into class values('American Political Parties','TuTh 2-3:15','20 AVW',619023588);
insert into class values('Social Cognition','Tu 6:30-8:40','R15',159542516);
insert into class values('Perception','MTuWTh 3','Q3',489221823);
insert into class values('Multivariate Analysis','TuTh 2-3:15','R15',090873519);
insert into class values('Patent Law','F 1-2:50','R128',090873519);
insert into class values('Urban Economics','MWF 11','20 AVW',489221823);
insert into class values('Organic Chemistry','TuTh 12:30-1:45','R12',489221823);
insert into class values('Marketing Research','MW 10-11:15','1320 DCL',489221823);
insert into class values('Seminar in American Art','M 4','R15',489221823);
insert into class values('Orbital Mechanics','MWF 8','1320 DCL',011564812);
insert into class values('Dairy Herd Management','TuTh 12:30-1:45','R128',356187925);
insert into class values('Communication Networks','MW 9:30-10:45','20 AVW',141582651);
insert into class values('Optical Electronics','TuTh 12:30-1:45','R15',254099823);
insert into class values('Intoduction to Math','TuTh 8-9:30','R128',489221823);
insert into enrolled values(112348546,'Database Systems');
insert into enrolled values(115987938,'Database Systems');
insert into enrolled values(348121549,'Database Systems');
insert into enrolled values(322654189,'Database Systems');
insert into enrolled values(552455318,'Database Systems');
insert into enrolled values(455798411,'Operating System Design');
insert into enrolled values(552455318,'Operating System Design');
insert into enrolled values(567354612,'Operating System Design');
insert into enrolled values(112348546,'Operating System Design');
insert into enrolled values(115987938,'Operating System Design');
insert into enrolled values(322654189,'Operating System Design');
insert into enrolled values(567354612,'Data Structures');
insert into enrolled values(552455318,'Communication Networks');
insert into enrolled values(455798411,'Optical Electronics');
insert into enrolled values(301221823,'Perception');
insert into enrolled values(301221823,'Social Cognition');
insert into enrolled values(301221823,'American Political Parties');
insert into enrolled values(556784565,'Air Quality Engineering');
insert into enrolled values(099354543,'Patent Law');
insert into enrolled values(574489456,'Urban Economics');
```

My best attempt is correct, which is:

```
select age, level from (select age, level, count(level) as levelCount from student group by age, level order by age, levelCount desc) as counts group by age;
```

But it breaks the rules of standard sql where every selected value must be group by, which I don't do with the outer most select statement, level. I am taking advantage of MySQl's functionality to return non-aggregated data.

The question is how can I return the max of a count for each group that is created from a group by, while conforming to standard sql best practices.

```
select age, level, count(level) as levelCount from student group by age, level order by age, levelCount desc;
```

Please and thank you

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does that matter?

Comment: Yes, because depending on that, the answers would be different. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Yes, it is homework.

Comment: Pseudo-code works fine for me, if that is what your concern is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pain in MySQL.  One way is to use variables.  However, the simplest way uses `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick:

```
select age,
       substring_index(group_concat(level order by levelCount desc), ',', 1) as mode_level
from (select age, level, count(level) as levelCount
      from student
      group by age, level
      order by age, levelCount desc
     ) as counts
group by age;
```

(Statistically, what you are looking for is called the `mode`.)

Note:  This is a trick.  The intermediate space for `group_concat()` is -- by default -- 1,024 characters, so it could result in an out-of-space/overflow error.  This limit is easily increased.

Comment: I looked for a bit about a built in function or something but this good to know. Kind of like the limit 1 for max(count/sum/etc) from group by.

Comment: So in general what would another approach be to answer the question? I feel there could be an easier way overall but I went down 1 rabbit hole and just stuck with it.

Comment: @BryanBirchmeier . . . The next easiest way is to use variables.  The most correct, but most painful method involves running the aggregation twice.

Comment: Out of curiosity how would that be different from how I originally did it? I aggregated it twice, I am assuming you are referring to a different structure then what I did.

Comment: @BryanBirchmeier . . . Your second method uses `group by` incorrectly, because there are unaggregated columns in the `select`.

Comment: Okay, so what would a correct use of double aggregation look like, roughly?